# State transition graph for a table with a whole column with don't cares

Tags: automation

[image: state transition table]

I have this state transition table and I want to draw the state transition graphs

Didn't have problems until I reached the last column with the state 11 where the whole column consists of don't cares

How do I handle such don't care situations?

Comment: that is a row, not a column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In don't care situations you can either do a transition to any state you want or do no transition at all. Usually, those don't care mean that they should not be achieved in a proper transition sequence but can be implemented in any way in order to optimize the code/circuit used to implement that automaton/FSM.

Comment: Thanks. Well so If I have don't cares I can simply ignore them?

Comment: For this I would put all back to the beginning for automation reasons but I guess I could ignore them at all?

Comment: If they are don't cares you can ignore them. If they are some type of "XX this never should happen" you should go to some state that fixes that behavior, or maybe reset the whole FSM.